# struts 2.3.8 have error

Tags: struts2-json-plugin

I using struts 2.3.8, it cannot have **TextUtils** Class in **xwork2.util** package, but struts 2.2.5 have class

Any change from that,..

i used follwing jars

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
asm-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.10.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-4.1.10.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jsonplugin-0.34.jar
jtds-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
servlet-api.jar
sitemesh-2.4.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
```

spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.3.8.jar
struts2-core-2.3.8.jar
struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1.jar
struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.8.jar
xwork-core-2.3.8.jar

Comment: I have the error i used jsonplugin.o.34.jar it cannot worked in struts2.3.8, now i used struts2-plugin.jar